# How is a stop order price different from an ask price

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy

If I buy a stock for 40$ and the best current ask is 41$. And let us say I put a stop loss at 35$.
Now by putting a stop at 35$, am I not basically saying that I am willing to sell this stock for 35 $? If yes, then basically this 35$ becomes the new Ask price and since it is the best Ask price,it should be filled immediately.

Yet it does not work like that (thankfully). Where is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop order is triggered when the market reaches the price you set. Until then - its not on the books. Your understanding is wrong in that you don't go to read [the definition of the term](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stoporder.asp).

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate how a market maker can 'run stops' since stop orders are not visible on the book. I can post separate question if required.

Comment: A stop order is a type of conditional order. Once the conditions are met, in this case the price falls to the stop loss level, then the stop will be triggered and the order to sell will go through.